# Android autocompletetextview not displaying correct dropdown menu

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

In the settings screen of my Android project I am using multiple autocompletetextviews each wrapped in TextInputLayout to serve as drop-down menus. Each drop-down menu is a weather condition like sunny, rainy etc. and the user can choose a music genre they would like to associate with a certain weather condition.

In the settings fragment, I am getting a reference to the menus and setting an adapter to each, and then I iterate over the list of weather conditions to set the saved music choice for each.

The issue is that when I save a genre to a weather condition, that saved genre then becomes the only option in the drop down menu for all autocompletetextviews.

Here is what the screen looks like:

[image: Settings screen]

and here is what it should look like / what it currently looks like when no genre is saved:

[image: Settings screen 2]

Here is the xml layout:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/music_preferences"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/foggy_dropdown_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            >
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/foggy_auto_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                />


        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/rainy_dropdown_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            >
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/rainy_auto_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sunny_dropdown_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            >
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/sunny_auto_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/snowy_dropdown_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            >
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/snowy_auto_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/cloudy_dropdown_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            >
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/cloudy_auto_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and here is the relevant code from the fragment class:

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        permissionHelper = PermissionHelper(requireActivity())
        val genres = resources.getStringArray(R.array.music_genres)
        val adapterItems = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.music_preference_item, genres)
        binding.foggyAutoTv.setAdapter(adapterItems)
        binding.rainyAutoTv.setAdapter(adapterItems)
        binding.sunnyAutoTv.setAdapter(adapterItems)
        binding.cloudyAutoTv.setAdapter(adapterItems)
        binding.snowyAutoTv.setAdapter(adapterItems)

        val weatherConditions = listOf(
            WeatherCondition.FOGGY,
            WeatherCondition.RAINY,
            WeatherCondition.SUNNY,
            WeatherCondition.SNOWY,
            WeatherCondition.CLOUDY
        )

        weatherConditions.forEach { condition ->
            prefViewModel.getMusicPreferences().onEach { musicPreferences ->
                    val castedMusicPreferences = musicPreferences as? Map<WeatherCondition, String>
                    val autoCompleteTextView = when (condition) {
                        WeatherCondition.FOGGY -> binding.foggyAutoTv
                        WeatherCondition.RAINY -> binding.rainyAutoTv
                        WeatherCondition.SUNNY -> binding.sunnyAutoTv
                        WeatherCondition.SNOWY -> binding.snowyAutoTv
                        WeatherCondition.CLOUDY -> binding.cloudyAutoTv
                    }
                val savedPreference = castedMusicPreferences?.get(condition)
                if (savedPreference != null) {
                    // If a preference is saved, set the saved genre as the text
                    autoCompleteTextView.setText(savedPreference)
                    autoCompleteTextView.hint = condition.name // Display weather condition as a hint
                } else {
                    // If no preference is saved, let the hint handle displaying the weather condition
                    autoCompleteTextView.hint = condition.name // Display weather condition as a hint
                }
                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapterItems)

                autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                        val selectedItem = adapterItems.getItem(position)
                        castedMusicPreferences?.let {
                            val musicPreference = mapOf(condition to selectedItem!!)
                            prefViewModel.savePreferences( musicPreference)
                        }
                    }
                autoCompleteTextView.post { autoCompleteTextView.performCompletion() }
            }.launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
        }
```